# How to get combined output from two or more than two queries?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have one table `ABC`. I am using queries

```
select count(*) from ABC where COLA=123; //output is 3
```

`select count(*) from ABC WHERE COLA=321; //output is 6`

I want both output combined like

```
| someColumnName |
|    3           |
|    6           |
```

Is there any way to frame query so that I can achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `UNION` between your two queries:

```
select count(*) as someColumnName  from ABC where COLA=123
union
select count(*) from ABC WHERE COLA=321;
```

Comment: If your only restriction is on the same field for each query, use the solution in the answer of @xQbert.
If you have multiples, differents conditions on your queries use `union`

Comment: both answers are fine but in my situation your's one is working with `UNION ALL`

Answer (score 4):

use a group by and where clause.

```
SELECT count(*) as SomeColumnName
FROM ABC 
WHERE COLA in (123,321)
GROUP BY ColA
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another option:

```
SELECT count(*) as SomeColumnName
FROM ABC 
WHERE COLA = 123 
   OR COLA = 321
GROUP BY COlA;
```

:)

Comment: This answer brings nothing new, it is the same idea as @xQbert.

Comment: In fact `IN` might be error-prone, if you have many values inside the brackets (1000++). Some time ago I had a (generated) query with more than 1000 items and the whole production database (ORACLE v9) stopped working. `OR` or `UNION` fixed that. Might seem strange, but it happened .... so it does bring something new :)

Comment: yes, with your comment, this make more sense. In fact, you can also combine the two `COLA IN (...999 values...) OR COLA IN ( ...999 values...) ....`